Calculate gradient with chain rule using additions
I am taking Karpathy's course, specifically I am on the first video. There is a step in the development of micrograd that I don't fully understand. Specifically  in this section, when he talks about if the same node or parameter is used more than once, the correct way to calculate its gradient is to sum the gradients from the different parts of the graph where it has been used. According to the video, the explanation is on the Wikipedia page for the chain rule in the "Multivariable case" section.
I have done various manual tests and indeed the gradients are correctly calculated by summing the contributions of the node at the different points where it intervenes, but I don't understand why the contributions should always be summed and this doesn't depend, for example, on the operation in which the node is involved.
Thank you very much for your help.

You seem to be asking about a proof of the multivariable chain rule so perhaps see https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=proof+multivariable+chain+rule
